# UICollectionViewCell to full screen transition

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview, segue, uicollectionviewcell

Is it possible to create a segue (or some sort of transition animation) for tapping a UICollectionView cell to make it expand to be full screen?

Even expanding only the UIImageView within the cell and then swapping it out with a segue would work for me...

[image]